# Weglassen von Artikeln

Tags: grammar, usage, article

> Unter dem Dach gibt es ein weiteres Zimmer mit Balkon.

Dieser Satz stammt aus einem Lehrbuch. Wie soll ich mir hier den Nullartikel vor *Balkon* erklären? Ich habe das Kapitel über den Gebrauch des Nullartikels in der Grammatik von Helbig und Buscha gelesen und weitere Erläuterungen im Netz gefunden. Dort werden zwar viele Fälle aufgezählt, in denen der Nullartikel gebraucht wird, aber keiner entspricht diesem Fall. Jetzt korrigiere ich Hausaufgaben von meinen Schülern und weiß nicht, ob ich die fehlenden Artikel in ähnlichen Sätzen als Fehler markieren soll oder nicht.

Answer (score 10):

Es handelt sich hier um eine feste Wendung. [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Artikel/Gebrauch/Fest.html?MenuId=Word633) schreibt dazu:

> Der Gebrauch (oder das Weglassen) des Artikels kann in festen Wendungen und Ausdrücken von den allgemeineren Regeln abweichen.

Von den Fällen, die dort unter "Ohne Artikel" aufgeführt werden, scheint mir "Feste Verbindungen Präposition + Nomen" am passendsten zu sein. In "Zimmer mit X" verwendet man X ohne Artikel, wenn es eine Eigenschaft des Zimmers beschreibt: mit Balkon, mit Aussicht, mit Parkett, mit Dusche / Frühstück / Vollpension (im Hotel) usw. Wobei man den Artikel nicht weglassen *muss* (solange keine andere Regel greift). "... ein weiteres Zimmer mit einem Balkon" ist möglich, genauso wie "mit großem Balkon" oder "mit einem großen Balkon".

Comment: Wenn ich diese Erklärung annehme, Phrasen wie "ein Sofa mit Plasma-Fernseher" oder "ein Tisch mit Stuhl" wären dann falsch, weil der Plasma-Fernseher und der Stuhl keine Eigenschaften des Sofas bzw. des Tisches sind, verstehe ich es richtig? Und noch eine Frage, außer diesen Fällen mit Präpositionen bin ich im Bereich der Wohnung mehreren Nullartikeln begegnet. Kannst Du mir bitte auch die folgenden Fälle erklären? 1) "Das Haus hat Keller." 2) "Im ersten Stock ist Schlafzimmer."

Comment: @dendalion, 1) und 2) sind grammatikalisch falsch. Woher hast Du die?

Comment: Bei Sofa und Tisch wäre mehr Kontext nötig, um es definitiv zu entscheiden. Bei einem Sofa mit eingebautem TV (gibt's sowas?) könnte es z.B. auch ohne Artikel gehen. 1) und 2) sind falsch, wobei 1) umgangssprachlich oder regional vielleicht grad noch durchgehen könnte. Aber wenn Du da Erklärungen brauchst, solltest Du eher eine eigene Frage stellen und sagen, warum Du zweifelst. (Rein grammatikalisch wäre 1) korrekt, wenn Keller als Plural mit unbestimmter Anzahl gemeint ist, oder Keller im Sinne von "Kellerraum" gebraucht wird. Ist aber unüblich.)

Comment: @Karl Wenn ich sowas wie 1) und 2) google, kommt es vor. Vielleicht ist es nur gekürztes Ausdrücken in Anzeigen oder so? Ich selber würde sowas nie schreiben, aber ich zögere, es in den Hausaufgaben zu korrigieren, wenn es offensichtlich auch Muttersprachler (zumindest manchmal) so benutzen. Ich will kein Präskriptivist sein.

Comment: @dendalion Ich würde den »Tisch mit Stuhl« gelten lassen. Das »Sofa mit Fernseher« klingt für meine Ohren allerdings komisch. 1) und 2) sind typische Beispiele des sogenannten Türken- oder Russendeutschs.

Comment: Weder "Haus hat Keller" nach "Im ersten Stock ist Schlafzimmer" sind grammatikalisch richtig. Und FALLS das regional gebräuchlich sein sollte, dann ist es bei schriftlichen Hausaufgaben trotzdem falsch

Comment: @dendalion Muttersprachler sagen sowas nicht, es sei denn sie äffen grad Ausländerdeutsch nach.

Comment: Ich habe "Das Haus hat Keller" gegoogelt und bin auf "Das Haus hat Keller, EG, OG und einen Dachboden plus Anbau" gestoßen. Da kann der Artikel weggelassen werden, da zwei oder mehr Nomen in engen Zusammenhang gebracht und mit "und" verbunden werden (http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Artikel/Gebrauch/Ohne.html#Anchor-Doppelformen-49575)

Comment: Nebenbei, ein Ursprung des sparsamen Gebrauchs von Artikeln (und auch von "und") im Zusammenhang mit Wohnungsbeschreibungen mag im häufigen Vorkommen in Kleinanzeigen liegen

Answer (score 5):

In Kürze: Beide Varianten sind korrekt. Ich habe die entsprechenden Grammatikregeln nicht zur Hand. Allerdings verstehe ich beide Varianten leicht unterschiedlich.

> […] ein Zimmer mit *einem* Balkon.

Mit unbestimmtem Artikel ist ein Zimmer gemeint, dessen Balkon noch einmal extra hervorgehoben wird. Es handelt sich um genau *ein* Zimmer mit *einem* Balkon.

> […] ein Zimmer *mit Balkon.*

Mit Nullartikel erscheint das ganze Konstrukt, wie Matthias schon geantwortet hat, als zusammengehörende Wendung, analog zu »zwei Zimmer mit Küche und Bad« oder »ein Eis mit Waffel«.

Im zweiten Fall (Nullartikel) empfinde ich Zimmer und Balkon als viel stärker zusammengehörig als im ersten Fall (mit unbestimmtem Artikel). Dafür könnten es bei Nullartikel im Zweifelsfall auch zwei Balkone sein (Süd- und Westseite), während mit unbestimmtem Artikel garantiert nur *ein* Balkon erreichbar ist.

Comment: Die Teile mit »*links/rechts*« und »*man muss durch das Zimmer*« verstehe ich nicht. Was ist damit gemeint? Auch wenn ich sage »*ein Zimmer mit einem Balkon*« werde ich den Balkon auch nur erreichen, wenn das Zimmer, von dem er abgeht, vorher betrete.

Comment: @Matthias Ich habs mal anders formuliert. Ich will mich wirklich an dem »kann baulich getrennt sein« nicht aufhängen ;).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Siehe Kommentar darüber.

Comment: @Jan ich finde es so tatsächlich besser. Am wichtigsten scheint mir, dass die Variante mit Artikel den Balkon stärker hervorhebt.