# No article after "ohne" and "mit"

Tags: article

These are sentences from my German textbook:

*Ohne Schlüssel hätten wir im Auto übernachten müssen.*

*Ohne Dosenöffner hätten wir nichts zu essen gehabt.*

*Mit Badeanzug hätten wir uns im See erfrischen können.*

*Mit Boot hätten wir in das Restaurant auf der anderen Seite des Sees fahren können.*

Why are there no articles? Why not 'Ohne **den** Schlüssel' or 'Mit **einem** Badeanzug'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mit großem Balkon - no article?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44636/mit-gro%c3%9fem-balkon-no-article)

Comment: I asked a similar question here: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/61328/43989

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving out the article denotes a *concept* or a *state* rather than particular thing. For instance:

> Ohne Dosenöffner hätten wir nichts zu essen gehabt.

This is not about one particular can opener or the other, this is about the *state of being with (or without) any can opener*.

> Ohne einen Dosenöffner hätten wir nichts zu essen gehabt.

This is similar but a little more specific: without a - any - can opener we would have had nothing to eat, but we had one. Not a specific one, because any other would have done too, but one we had.

> Ohne den (diesen) Dosenöffner hätten wir nichts zu essen gehabt.

This is talking about a specific specimen of can opener. *This one*, not any other one, saved us from having nothing to eat.

> Ohne Schlüssel hätten wir im Auto übernachten müssen.

This is also talking about the *concept of being without any key*, but - not every key opens every lock - we could say:

> Ohne *diesen* (den richtigen!) Schlüssel hätten wir im Auto übernachten müssen, aber mit *einem* (falschen) Schlüssel wären wir auch nicht besser dran gewesen.

And, because this is not only possible with "mit" and "ohne":

> *Schlüssel* zu haben, ist was Wunderbares, aber *einen passenden Schlüssel* zu haben ist noch besser.

**Addendum**:

After some searching I found a similar thread here which also cites (or, at least hints, to some sources:

[Weglassen von Artikeln (in German)](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25789/weglassen-von-artikeln)

[Was man über den Gebrauch des Nullartikels wissen sollte](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/files/grammatik/nomenbegleiter/nullartikel.pdf)

Comment: Note that the special thing here is the lack of an article in the singular, your last example will be interpreted as an indefinite plural, so that's not parallel. -- Do you have a source for your explanation? (I had the same thought, though)

Comment: @The last example *could* be plural, but doesn't have to be: "Einen Schlüssel zu haben ....". In fact it is ambiguous. As for the source: alas, I have none at hand, but will search for one.

Comment: @Alazon: I found one and edited it in.

Comment: In my judgement, "Schlüssel zu haben" could only be understood as a plural. You just get a grammatical singular in cases like "Geld / Glück haben" (which also occur without article otherwise)

Comment: @Alazon: there is "Geld haben" (ist Glückssache) und "Das Geld haben" (möchte ich auch). "Geld haben" is the state of "being rich", whereas "das Geld haben" means "that sort/amount of money". Likewise with "Glück" or "Zeit": "*Die* Zeit möchte ich haben." = "I'd like to have as much time on my hands as you seem to have."